# Yii2 Validation rule: How to check datetime and place does not collidate with another entry?

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, yii2-validation

This is my table `event`

[image]

As you see

Transaction  1

```
time_begin: 2016-03-10 07:00:00    
time_end:   2016-03-10 08:00:00  
place:      1
```

If user makes a Transaction 2 and then selects

```
time_begin: 2016-03-10 07:15:00     
time_end:   2016-03-10 07:45:00 
place:      1
```

How to make a custom validation rule that checks datetime and place is not used in another transaction?

So I have tried this:

```
// models.php

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['title', 'description', 'time_begin', 'time_end', 'place'], 'required'],
        [['description', 'status'], 'string'],
        [['time_begin', 'time_end'], 'safe'],
        [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 150],
        [['place'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['remark'], 'string', 'max' => 145],
        [['time_end'], 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'time_begin','operator'=>'>','message'=>''],
        [['place', 'time_begin'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['place', 'time_begin'],'message'=>'time and place is busy place select new one.'],
        [['place'], 'checkDate','skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}


public function checkDate($attribute, $params)
{
    $a = Event::find()->where(['>=', 'time_begin', ($this->time_begin)])->count();
    $b = Event::find()->where(['<=', 'time_end', ($this->time_end)])->count();
    $c = Event::find()->where(['=', 'place', ($this->place)])->count();
    $d = ($this->time_begin);
    $e = ($this->time_end);
    $f = ($this->place);
    if (($d > $a) && ($f = $c))
    {
         $this->addError($attribute, 'This place and time is busy, selcet new place or change time.');
    }
}
```

It won't work because this `if (($d > $a) && ($f = $c))` is wrong.

But I don't know how to write the condition for check that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this help:

```
public function checkDate($attribute, $params)
{
    $thereIsAnOverlapping = Event::find()->where(
        ['AND',
            ['place' => $this->place],
            ['<=', 'time_begin', $this->time_end],
            ['>=', 'time_end', $this->time_begin]
        ])->exists();

    if ($thereIsAnOverlapping) {
         $this->addError($attribute, 'This place and time is busy, selcet new place or change time.');
    }
}
```

This checks, if there is another event that has the same room AND has an time overlapping (completely or partly).

With this I think you could omit the rule for `['place', 'time_begin']`.

Comment: thank you sir. but got some issue. i'm posted in answers 2.

Comment: @ChonjaroenChauynoo I've updated my answer. Luckily, it has got even simpler! Give it a try!